# Can I use the jqgrid with JSON Web Tokens?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jwt

I want to receive and edit data in the jqgrid table using JSON Web Tokens. Authorized users should be able to edit data, unauthorized - read data.

Comment: What have you tried and what problems are you having?

Comment: I was looking for a ready solution for the github, but I did not find (

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend an off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.